# RHEL6: Switch Python back to original default version

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, python-2.6, rhel

I am using RHEL6 which came with Python 2.6.6 pre-installed on it as the default python executable.

Some months ago, I installed Python 2.7 on it and switched the default python version to 2.7 (yes, idiot move I now realize). So now when I type `python` it runs Python 2.7.

Also: `which python` gives me `/usr/local/bin/python`

As you might expect, and I only found out recently, this has caused issues when trying to run some system scripts which depend on the version being 2.6. The 2.6 installation still exists and I can run it by either `python2` or `python2.6`.

Also: `which python2` gives `/usr/bin/python2` and which `python2.6` gives `/usr/bin/python2.6`

The problem is that I do not remember how I switched the default version to 2.7. I know I didn't create any alias, because I can't find any in the `~/.bashrc` file.

Does anyone have any advice on how I can revert back by changes so that Python 2.6.6 becomes the default once again? I can provide any further information that might be necessary to analyze this problem. Moreover, I have a couple of other people around me who are also using RHEL6 and haven't played around with their python installations, so if I need to copy any original scripts from `/usr/bin/` to get this fixed I can get it from them, as long as I know what to get.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

---

Responses to Barun Sharma:

Running `ls -l /usr/local/bin/python*` gives me:

`-rwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 6111394 Jan 16  2015 /usr/local/bin/python
-rwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 6111394 Jan 16  2015 /usr/local/bin/python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root    1624 Jan 16  2015 /usr/local/bin/python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root       9 Dec 26  2014 /usr/local/bin/python3 -> python3.4
-rwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 8777236 Dec 26  2014 /usr/local/bin/python3.4
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      17 Dec 26  2014 /usr/local/bin/python3.4-config -> python3.4m-config
-rwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 8777236 Dec 26  2014 /usr/local/bin/python3.4m
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root    3013 Dec 26  2014 /usr/local/bin/python3.4m-config
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      16 Dec 26  2014 /usr/local/bin/python3-config -> python3.4-config
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      16 Jan 16  2015 /usr/local/bin/python-config -> python2.7-config`

Comment: 1) `rm /usr/local/bin/python`.       2)`ln -s /usr/bin/python2.6 /usr/local/bin/python` And you should be done.

Answer (score 0):

create a soft link:-

```
ln -s /usr/bin/python2 /usr/local/bin/python
```

Or directly point `/usr/local/bin/python` to your python2.6 binary(i.e where   ~/usr/bin/python2` points).

Follow these steps:-

1) `rm /usr/local/bin/python`. This would remove the soft link. But python 2.7 will still be there. You can check `/usr/local/bin/python2.7`.

2) `ln -s /usr/local/bin/python2.6 /usr/local/bin/python`. Symbolic link from python to python2.6

Also when you are working on python, I would advise you to use `virtual environment` and install your required python version and other packages. I generally do not install packages to system python when it is required for a specific project(rather do it on a virtual env).

Comment: Thanks for your response! However, when I run the command you suggested `ln -s /usr/bin/python2 /usr/local/bin/python`, I get the following:

`ln: creating symbolic link \`/usr/local/bin/python': File exists`

Comment: Also, `/usr/bin/python2` points to `python`.

`$ ls -l /usr/bin/python2`

gives

`lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 6 Feb 25  2014 /usr/bin/python2 -> python`

Comment: Please check the edit. And what is the result of `ls -l /usr/bin/python*`?

Comment: [Sorry, but it seems that I cannot add newline characters into my comments!]

The result of `ls -l /usr/bin/python*` was initially: 

`-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 9032 Nov 21  2013 /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    6 Feb 25  2014 /usr/bin/python2 -> python
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 9032 Nov 21  2013 /usr/bin/python2.6`

Comment: After removing the existing soft link and running `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.6 /usr/bin/python` as you suggested, the result of the above is: `lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   18 Sep 13 15:43 /usr/bin/python -> /usr/bin/python2.6
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    6 Feb 25  2014 /usr/bin/python2 -> python
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 9032 Nov 21  2013 /usr/bin/python2.6
`

Comment: `python` still takes me to the Python 2.7 interpreter though.

Comment: Oops. I am really sorry. Your `which python` points to `/usr/local/bin/python`, So you would have to make these changes in `/usr/local`. Hope you get it. Or can you post the result for `ls -l /usr/local/bin/python*`.

Comment: I have added the latest result into the original post (better formatting). So you suggest that I remove the symbolic link created `/usr/bin/python -> /usr/bin/python2.6` and create a new link from `/usr/local/bin/python` to `/usr/bin/python2.6`?

Comment: Thanks you so much for your help @Barun! Finally managed to get it work, by putting a link from `/usr/local/bin/python` to `/usr/bin/python2.6`. `python` now opens python 2.6.6 and the system script that I was trying to run is also working!

Comment: Great. Can you upvote and accept this answer now. That would help us both get some reputation points. :)

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your system back to normal, the way to add new versions of Python 2.7, 3.3, or 3.4 to RHEL (6 or 7) is to utilize Software Collections (aka RHSCL or SCL) which install along side the original Python versions.  There are many other languages, databases, web servers, and other tools, too.  RHSCLs are included in most RHEL subscriptions.

To get started:  http://developers.redhat.com/products/softwarecollections/overview/

You can also find information here:  https://access.redhat.com/products/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/Developer/#rhscl=&dev-page=5

OR here:  http://developerblog.redhat.com/tag/software-collections/